# Deleting RecyclerView items

Tags: java, android

I am using a Recyclerview to display item in MainActivity. this might have been asked but in did not find any particular solution. the way I am saving the items is by serialization now the problem is how can I implement delete function on each item of Recycler view? I created my own delete function in utils.delete but i get NPE.

if I call `notifyDataSetChanged();` it only deletes it from the view and not the saved file

please help.

ItemAdapter class:

```
public class Itemadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Itemadapter.itemviewholder> {
  static ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
 Context mcontext;

private String mFilename = utils.EXTRAS_NOTE_FILENAME;


public Itemadapter(MainActivity mainActivity, int item, ArrayList<Item> items)
{
       this.items = items;
}


@Override
public itemviewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
 View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
    itemviewholder itemviewholder = new itemviewholder(view);
    return itemviewholder;





}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final itemviewholder holder, final int position) {
  Item item = items.get(position);
    holder.postnumber.setText(item.getPost_number());
    holder.itemname.setText(item.getItem_name());







}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();

  }
public class itemviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements   View.OnClickListener

 {



TextView itemname,postnumber,ico;
private PopupMenu popupMenu;
 ImageButton ico1;

public itemviewholder(View view)
  {
  super(view);


  itemname =  view.findViewById(R.id.itemdetailsdisplay);
  postnumber =  view.findViewById(R.id.itemnuberdisplay);
  ico1 = view.findViewById(R.id.test);
  view.setOnClickListener(this);
  ico1.setOnClickListener(this);



}


@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
     final Item mLoadeditem = utils.getitembyfilename(v.getContext(),mFilename);

    if (v.getId() == ico1.getId()){
       // Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               popupMenu = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(),v);
               popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.recycler_item_menu);
               popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                       @Override
                      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                       switch (item.getItemId()){
                           case R.id.item_delete:
            //delete file
                            utils.delete(v.getContext(),mLoadeditem.getPost_number()+utils.FILE_EXTENSION);
                             items.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                               Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"item deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                              break;
                           case R.id.item_share:
            //share info
                               Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"item shared",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       break;
                     }

                          return false;
                     }
                   });popupMenu.show();






        }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ROW PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


  }
 }
}
```

utils class:

```
public class utils {

public static final String  FILE_EXTENSION = ".bin";
public static final String EXTRAS_NOTE_FILENAME = "EXRAS_NOTES_FILENAME";

public static boolean save(Context context, Item item){
String filename = String.valueOf(item.getPost_number()) +FILE_EXTENSION;

    FileOutputStream fos;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    try {
        fos= context.openFileOutput(filename,context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(item);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
        //something  went wrong
    }


return true;

}
public static ArrayList<Item> getallsaveditems(Context context){
ArrayList <Item> items= new ArrayList<>();
File filesdir = context.getFilesDir();
ArrayList<String> itemsfiles = new ArrayList<>();
for(String file : filesdir.list()){
    if(file.endsWith(FILE_EXTENSION)){
        itemsfiles.add(file);
    }
}

FileInputStream fis;
ObjectInputStream ois;

for(int i=0; i<itemsfiles.size();i++){
    try {
        fis = context.openFileInput(itemsfiles.get(i));
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        items.add((Item) ois.readObject());
        fis.close();
        ois.close();
    }catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
 return items;
 }

public static Item getitembyfilename(Context context,String filename) {
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
    if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
        Log.v("utils", "file exists" + filename);
        FileInputStream fis;
        ObjectInputStream ois;
    try {
        fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Item item = (Item) ois.readObject();
        fis.close();
        ois.close();
        return item;
    } catch (IOException |ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    }else {
        return null;




    }

}









public static void delete(Context ctx ,String filename) {
File dir = ctx.getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(dir,filename);
    if(file.exists()){
        file.delete();
    }


}


}
```

Comment: This question doesn't have much to do with RecyclerViews, you're problem is with deleting items from the database. Do you know that the way you are deleting items works when not using a recyclerview?

Comment: I get your point but can you please answer the question?

Comment: Without getting the information I asked about, I don't know the answer.

Comment: Have a look in save() in utils class this is the method i use to store. Now there is also delete() in the end of the class but it is not working can you tell why?